# How to enable double tab autocompletion list in csh?

Tags: command-line, autocomplete, csh

I've worked in Linux before where when I press tab it autocompletes until it becomes ambiguous. If I pressed tab twice at that point it would give me a list of all possible completions.

My current Linux environment does not have the second feature(enabled?). So if I press tab it will autocomplete but it won't list all possible completions after that.

How can I add/enable this feature?

EDIT: turns out it's in csh not bash

Comment: What environment is this? Yes, we are accustomed to be pampered by Linux and GNU tools.

Comment: Redhat Release 5.6

Comment: I don't know if it is configured exactly the same on a RH (I don't have one to check atm), but there should be a `/etc/bash_completion` file coming with bash, which you only need to source In you own session startup scripts (or enable site wide in `/etc/bash.bashrc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

in `~/.cshrc` put

```
set filec
set autolist
```

if you don't want list when autocompletes, use

```
set autolist = ambiguous 
set complete = enhance
```

Comment: It's not quite what I want in that a single tab autcompletes AND lists, but I'm not sure you can do better.

Comment: You may be right. If i find anything to add i'll post it ASAP

Answer (score 1):

To `set autolist` to show choices only when completion fails and adds no new characters to the word being completed:

```
set autolist ambiguous
```